# Integrating Azure Service Bus in DOT NET 6

Tags: .net, .net-core, azure-servicebus-topics

I'm trying to Integrate Azure Service Bus (Consumer/Subscriber) in DOTNET 6.
But, its not working the following is the code

```
builder.Services.AddServiceBusNotifications(builder.Configuration);
builder.Services.AddScoped<NewUserCreatedEventHandler>();

var app = builder.Build();
ConfigureServiceBus(app);

static void ConfigureServiceBus(IApplicationBuilder applicationBuilder)
{
    var eventBus = applicationBuilder.ApplicationServices.GetRequiredService<IEventBus>();
    eventBus.Subscribe<NewUserCreatedEvent, NewUserCreatedEventHandler>();
}
```

But I'm not able to get the messages from Azure Service Bus Topic, the same was working fine with DOTNET 5
Does anybody have any Idea about this one.

Comment: May i know do you have installed all the required `nuget packages` for .net 6 . And could you please share `.csproj` to understand more , this may help us to give a proper resolution.

Comment: CRPROJ file too large to paste over here.

Comment: Okay just add your `nuget packages` only that you have installed with version . And please default project selected as `QueueReceiver` .

Comment: AutoMapperVersion="9.0.0AutoMapper.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjectionVersion="7.0.0Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearerVersion="3.1.3Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJsonVersion="3.1.3Microsoft.Azure.CosmosVersion="3.17.1Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBusVersion="5.2.0Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCoreVersion="6.0.1Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.BinderVersion="6.0.0MySql.DataVersion="8.0.25MySql.Data.EntityFrameworkCoreVersion="8.0.22NancyVersion="2.0.0NLogVersion="4.7.7NLog.Web.AspNetCoreVersion="4.10.0Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySqlVersion="6.0.0Swashbuckle.AspNetCoreVersion="6.2.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But I'm not able to get the messages from Azure Service Bus Topic, the
> same was working fine with DOTNET 5

We have tried to Integrating Azure Service Bus using `.net6` at it works perfectly to send and receive message from service bus at our end.

- Downloaded basic Sample code from [***`GitHub`***](https://github.com/mohamadlawand087/v14-AzureServiceBusWithAspNet5) which is using ASP.NET 5 , and we upgrade it to `.net 6`  and downloaded the following `nuget packages` `Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus` latest version .

`.csproj`file

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\SampleShared\SampleShared.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus" Version="5.2.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

</Project>
```

***NOTE***:- ***Make sure that you have updated the version and packages for all `sender/Receiver/Sample shared` projects.***

- Created Azure service bus in portal and added queue in this . Copied *Connection string* from *servicebus namespace* and provide those in sender/receiver .

[image]
[image]
[image]

NOTE:- ***Make sure to provide the correct connection string from Azure service bus> Shared access signature***. Else `404` error will occur if we provide queue connection string

- After providing connection string in sender and receiver go to sender project path and build and run the application using `dotnet build` & `dotnet run`:-

[image]

Provide the message details to be shown in receiver
[image]

Goto receiver project and run the project once build is done then run the project
will get output of the message which we send through sender.

***OUTPUT:***

[image]

For more information please refer this Blog: [***USING AZURE SERVICE BUS QUEUES WITH ASP.NET CORE SERVICES***](https://damienbod.com/2019/04/23/using-azure-service-bus-queues-with-asp-net-core-services/)